# Using vb.NET and ClosedXML to search an Excel worksheet

Tags: vb.net, closedxml

I have a simple spreadsheet which I named CodeWS with 3 columns:

```
 A          B          C
CODE   DESCRIPTION   GL_ACCT
1000     TEST 1       8520
2000     TEST 2       8600
3000     TEST 3       8647
```

My need to search Column A for a given value and then retrieve Column C value of the same row.
For instance, I would search for "2000" in Column A and get the return value of 8600.

I set my search value and search range (which I hard-coded while I figure this out) and did a search:

```
Dim fVal As String = "2000"
Dim myrange = CodeWS.Range(CodeWS.Cell(1, "A"), CodeWS.Cell(3, "A")) 
Dim Results As IXLCells = myrange.Search(fVal)
```

This works to the point that I can see "Results" cell address A:2 returned in "RangesUsed" when I hover over "Results"

Now how to I return the contents of cell C:2 so I can use it in my program?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Results is a IEnumberable of IXCell.  So wouldn't be possible to hover over Results and inspect elements and their properties to tell you want you want to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you essentially want to do a `VLOOKUP`, so you can try in C#: `var value = CodeWS.Evaluate(@"=VLOOKUP(""2000"", A:C, 3, false)");`, or whatever the VB.NET equivalent of that statement is.

Comment: This worked great.  I was able to put variables in for my lookup value and range.  It returned column 3 as expected.

Comment: Great. Happy that it worked. You can mark my post as a valid answer, if you agree